# Is there a way to break this below Singleton code in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

This is a singleton class.

I wanted to know the ways to we break the singleton logic in this code

```
class Employee{ // class starts
    private Employee(){} // private constructor

    private static Employee emp; 
    /*static block*/

    static {    
        if (emp==null)
        {
            emp=new Employee(); 
        }
    }      
    /* static method*/          
    public static Employee getEmployee()
    {   
        return emp;  
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "break the singleton logic"?

Comment: what do you want to do with this class? question is not clear.

Comment: add final to Empoyee, remove the if statement as it's *always* true and it's good. Now it's fine, just looks written by a noob.

Comment: Are you asking? how to break singleton-ness of the above class? i.e. instantiate multiple instances of above class? :-o

Comment: @MukulGoel, you can't "*instantiate multiple instances of above class*" for the simple reason the c-tor is private

Comment: @bestsss yea I know but he is asking for "How we break the singleton logic in the code" So asking if that is what he wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also do below in constructor to avoid object creation by reflection

```
private Employee(){ 
if(emp!=null){
   throws new InstantiationError("singleton breached ");
}
```

}

Comment: this is entirely pointless. If you have access to reflection you can have access to unsafe and you can create the instance *without* even invoking the c-tor.

Answer (score 7):

You want just a single instance of `Employee`?

```
class Employee{ // class starts
   private Employee(){}
   public static final Employee INSTANCE = new Employee(); 
}
```

No getters needed, the code is safe as it stands, just use:

```
Employee.INSTANCE
```

Just a note: `Employee` sounds like a value object, seems unusual to have singleton value object.

UPDATE: seems like I finally understand what the question is about. This singleton is safe, unless some really heavy artilerry is used:

- making constructor `public` using reflection (see great answer by *Marko Topolnik*). I guess this can be avoided with some security manager settings
- Java serialization - not really possible, singleton would have to implement `Serializable`
- different class-loaders ([illustrated](http://geekandpoke.typepad.com/geekandpoke/2010/12/the-geekpoke-pattern-tip-of-the-week.html))

Besides these common gotchas, your code is fine, but not pretty. `static` initialization is guaranteed to run once and atomically, when class is loaded.

Comment: Seems that OP wants the exact opposite of this.

Comment: yup, Agree with @MarkoTopolnik, i guess he is asking for ways to breach the singleton class, i.e. have multiple instances.

Comment: I was only referring to breaking of singleton logic.             What if Employee Object is serialized once  and deserialized many times , I think we can break the singleton logic in that case.

Comment: @subramanya Your point with deserialization is correct, but this would only be a sign of an ill-imlemented singleton. A serializable singleton must implement `readResolve` to return the singleton. See [this post](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/DeserSingle.html) for a complete example.

Comment: @subramanya: I updated my answer, thanks for all the comments

Comment: @subramanya , please update your question with what you mean by breaking the singleton logic as you mentioned here in comments.

Comment: *making constructor public using reflection* - any (not some) sane security manager would prevent that, if you can use `setAccessible` basically you have access to Unsafe too (or anything else). A different classloader is NOT applicable, as it's entirely different class, it'd be the same to say "different processes".

Answer (score 5):

If you want access to multiple `Employee` instances, it is enough to make the constructor public. If you also want all the current clients of this class to receive a new instance every time instead of the singleton instance, then implement `getEmployee()` as  `{ return new Employee(); }`. You can then delete the `private static` variable and the `static` initializer block.

Third, if you cannot change the source code, but want to get many `Employee` instances anyway, the only way is resorting to reflection:

```
try {
  final Constructor<Employee> c = Employee.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
  c.setAccessible(true);
  final Employee e = c.newInstance();
} catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
```

Fourth, if your question is really about protecting the singleton from breaches, and the singleton is indeed serializable (not shown in your example), then the class must implement the `readResolve` method that is implicitly involved in the deserialization mechanism:

```
protected Object readResolve() {
    return emp;
}
```

Note that nothing can protect against reflection, except for enabling a `SecurityManager` and configuring the appropriate privileges.

Comment: good explanation ..But i would like to know the exact benefit of this technique. Technique thinking when this is useful ? and As per my thought, If you are creating multiple instances of a SingleTon Class then those objects will not be garbage collected until we take the server down.

Comment: @GunjanShah It is not clear which technique you have in mind. The answer discusses many techniques.

Comment: FYI: readResolve works only if the class is final (or non-public, assuming package sealing w/ sec.mngr), otherwise it can be extended, the stream modified to the extended class and then returns the extended instance w/ readResolve overridden.

Comment: that should be just as fine... but then you risk readObject (of the subclass) to escape the instance. (edit: forgot to mention the obvious readObject must be private, hence final, regardless what javadoc says )Doh I should become some boring security consultant.

Answer (score 0):

Want multiple instances? Piece of cake:

```
    Constructor<Employee> constructor = Employee.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
    constructor.setAccessible(true);
    Employee wtf = constructor.newInstance();
    assertSame(wtf, Employee.getEmployee());
```

There are two ways to protect singletons. The second best is using a one-element enum:

```
enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;
    void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("Doing something");
    }
}

// Usage:
Singleton.INSTANCE.doSomething();
```

The best and simplest way is to not use singletons at all.

Comment: "One element enum" does not prevent invoking the c-tor via reflection (enums DO have c-tors). Also enum as singleton is a very bad idea I have rant a few times, regardless what J. Bloch tells you. It's automatic serializable and allows to co-exist 2+ instances of otherwise-meant-to-be-singleton-interface impl. In other words if you have access to invocation of private c-tors, the code has unlimited unsafe access to the entire process, so you might as well give up to protect the singleton.

Comment: If you try and invoke an enum ctor with reflection, you get an error message saying "Cannot reflectively create enum objects". Also, they handle serialization sensibly, so `deserialize(serialize(Singleton.INSTANCE)) == Singleton.INSTANCE`.

Comment: Hmm, the protection has been put somewhere in time, either way you can do it by bytecode generation then (the same way reflection does). Yes, enum handle serialization very well (they are serialized only by their name and not methods are invoked) however you do not wish to serialize singletons. Imagine you have 'interface Singleton', depending on the setup/config a different class may end up being the singleton of choice - if a serialized instance holding a reference to the singleton is deserialized, the singleton would be deserialized even though it might not be the one in the current system